Number of polynomial functions in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x_1, \, \ldots, \, x_n]$?
What is the number of polynomial functions in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x_1, \, \ldots, \, x_n]$?
(Here I define $p \sim q$ iff $p(x) = q(x)$ for all $x$.)
What about the case if we allow permutations? For example, $p(x) = x_1 x_4$ and $q(x) = x_5 x_7$ are deemed equal because we can permute $x_1$ with $x_5$ and $x_4$ with $x_7$, for example.
It is trivial to see, if we do not consider permutations, that there are at least $n$ equivalence classes. Consider the polynomials $p_i(x) = x_i$. Then take the vector $x$ with $x_k = \delta_k$ for some fixed $k$. Now
$$0 = p_i(x) \neq p_k(x) = 1,$$
unless of course $i=k$. And $1 \leq i \leq n$, so there are at least $n$ classes. Can we get an exact number?
I am also wondering about generalizations to other rings: here $R=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, but what about $R = \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ (if we have polynomials in $n$ variables, modulo $m$)?

Did you try using the Frobenius? If I understand correctly, the without permutation case is then reduced to counting functions where each individual degree is at most 1, since $p=2$ gives $x_i^2 \equiv x_i \mod 2$.

What you are asking for is the number of polynomial functions, not the number of polynomials,

By the way sometimes $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is used to mean $p$-adic integers, so it's better to either clarify that by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ you mean integers mod $n$, or use the unambiguous $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

The count up to permutation is quite hopeless in general, but here are some comments. The argument in X-Rui's answer generalizes to show that over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ the number of polynomial functions in $n$ variables is $q^{q^n}$; in particular, there are $\boxed{ p^{p^n} }$ polynomial functions $\bmod p$ for $p$ a prime. The Chinese remainder theorem can be used to show that polynomial functions $\bmod m$, where $m = \prod_i p_i$ is squarefree (a product of distinct primes $p_i$), are in bijection with tuples of polynomial functions $\bmod p_i$ for each of the prime factors of $m$, so the number of such functions is $\boxed{ \prod_i p_i^{p_i^n} }$ (note that this is much smaller than $m^{m^n}$). Things get more complicated if $m$ is not squarefree and I'm not sure what the answer is off the top of my head in that case.
Now let's consider the count up to permutation, working again over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ for simplicity. Write $V = \mathbb{F}_q^n$, which is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$. X-Rui's answer shows that polynomial functions in $n$ variables are in bijection with arbitrary functions $V \to \mathbb{F}_q$. The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on $V$ via permuting coordinates, and this induces an action on functions $V \to \mathbb{F}_q$. By Burnside's lemma, the number of orbits of this action is
$$\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} |\text{Fix}(\pi)|$$
where $|\text{Fix}(\pi)|$ denotes the number of fixed points of a permutation $\pi$ acting on functions $V \to \mathbb{F}_q$. It's not hard to see that a function is fixed iff it's constant on the orbits of $\pi$ acting on $V$, so the number of fixed points is $q^{|\text{Orb}(\pi)|}$ where $|\text{Orb}(\pi)|$ denotes the number of orbits of the action on $V$ (note that this is with respect to a different action than previously). So now we want to compute
$$\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{|\text{Orb}(\pi)|}.$$
The problem from here is that $|\text{Orb}(\pi)|$ is complicated. It can be computed by applying the argument above a second time, applying Burnside's lemma to the cyclic group generated by $\pi$ acting on $V$ thought of as the set of functions $[n] \to \mathbb{F}_q$ from an $n$-element set to $\mathbb{F}_q$; this cyclic group has order the $\text{lcm}$ of the lengths of the cycles appearing in the cycle decomposition of $\pi$, and the resulting sum appears to me to be quite complicated for an exponent, although it's not so bad if $\pi$ consists of a single prime cycle, for example.
This complication is here for a good reason: the objects we're counting are complicated. For example, if $p = 2$ we are counting the number of orbits of the action of $S_n$ on a set of size $2^{2^n}$ which can be identified with the set of subsets of the set of subsets of an $n$-element set $[n]$. In other words we're talking about isomorphism classes of some kind of undirected hypergraphs or incidence structures on $n$ vertices. These are very complicated objects to count up to isomorphism; already counting ordinary graphs up to isomorphism is difficult.
In a positive direction, Burnside's lemma at least gives us an easy lower bound: taking only the term of the above sum corresponding to the identity gives that the number of polynomial functions up to permutation is at least $\boxed{ \frac{1}{n!} q^{q^n} }$; this is, intuitively speaking, what the answer would be if polynomials did not have any nontrivial permutation symmetries. For example, plugging in $q = 2, n = 4$ gives that there are at least $2731$ polynomial functions in $4$ variables $\bmod 2$ up to permutation.

For the first paragraph, one step in the generalization of X-Rui's answer to $p > 2$ is that you define $\chi_i(x) = 1 - (x_i - a_i)^{p-1}$, so $\chi_i(x) = 1$ if $x_i = a_i$ and $\chi_i(x) = 0$ if $x_i \ne a_i$.

Not considering permutations, I think there should be $2^{2^n}$ polynomial functions.
The number of inputs is $2^n$, and outputs $2$, so total number of functions $\mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2$ is $2^{2^n}$. Also, every function can be given by a polynomial. We can construct a characteristic polynomial $p$ for each possible input $a = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ such that $p(x) = 1$ if and only if $x = a$, and by taking an appropriate sum of them we can get any function. To make the construction, first write $\chi_i(x) = \begin{cases}1 - x_i, &a_i = 0, \\ x_i, &a_i = 1.\end{cases}$ This $\chi_i(x) = 1$ if and only if $x_i = a_i$. Then, the product $\chi_a = \chi_1 \dots \chi_n$ satisfies $\chi_a(x) = 1 \iff \chi_i(x) = 1, \forall i \iff x_i = a_i,\ \forall i \iff x = a$ as required.
